# In cnosdb, the question about the wrong information when the ttl is negative

Tags: cnosdb

While using cnosdb, I got an error when I tried to set the ttl to a negative value:

sql:

```
alter database db set ttl '-365d';
```

error info:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: -365d is not a valid precision, use like 'ms', 'us', 'ns'"}
```

but the error message confused me, I wonder what it means? I'm not allowed to set negative values or I'm doing something wrong